# Serv-U problems with Windows Defender Antivirus and Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-10, ftp

We are using Serv-U FTP Server in a Windows 10 Pro machine. Starting two weeks ago, Windows Defender detects Serv-U as a threat and stops it. Serv-U was already in the antivirus list exceptions.

Anyone has experienced a similar issue? What to do to solve this situation?

Comment: It would be ideal if you could state which Anti-Virus you are using.

Comment: Windows defender, the built-in antivirus wich comes with Windows 10

Comment: Report the false positive to Microsoft, if it actually is a false positive, Microsoft will update the signature files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an exclusion to Windows Security.
If you trust a file, file type, folder, or a process that Windows Security has detected as malicious, you can stop Windows Security from alerting you or blocking the program by adding the file to the exclusions list.

1.Go to Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & thread protection.
2.Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.
[image]

3.Select Add an exclusion, and then select from files, folders, file types, or process. The exclusion will apply to subfolders within a folder as well.

Comment: Thanks, we've already done this. We hope it works!